# Creating 2 arrays from one array in python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am new to python coming from a Java background and am trying to create two arrays from a single array where the odd indexs are put in one array and the even index are put into another.

array one will contain indexs(0,2,4,6,8 etc.)
array two will contain indexs(1,3,5,7,9 etc.)

my current implementation is:

```
for i in range (0, len(originalArray) - 1):  
    if i % 2 == 0:
        Array1.append(originalArray[i])

    if i % 2 == 1:
        Array2.append(originalArray[i])

if len(originalArray) % 2 == 0:
    Array1.append(originalArray[-1])
```

Could anyone recommend a better way of doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list is named `a`

```
part1 = a[::2]
part2 = a[1::2]
```

Result:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[::2]
[1, 3, 5]
>>> a[1::2]
[2, 4, 6]
```

The slice syntax in python is `list[start:end:step]`. Using `list[::2]`, we get each second element from the list (the even ones). To get the odd elements, we add one to the list start index, and so use `list[1::2]`.

A more detailed explanation can be found here: [python list slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm not trying to create one array from two. It's the other way around.

Comment: Uh, sorry, updating the question

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your question

Comment: This is perfect. Could you explain what is happening with the colons? I am very new to python. Thanks

Comment: Added more explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, not as pythonic but I err on the side of readability:

```
Array1 = []
Array2 = []
tmp_array = [Array1, Array2]
for i in xrange(len(originalArray)):
    tmp_array[i % 2].append(originalArray[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
first_list = original_list[0::2]
second_list = original_list[1::2]
```

the result is:

```
first_list = [1,3,5,7]
second_list = [2,4,6,8]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
for element in originalArray:
    if originalArray.index(element) % 2 = 0:
        Array1.append(element)
    else:
        Array2.append(element)
```